# Pull data from one DB Server to another DB server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key, primary-key

I want to pull Few tables (33 Tables) from one DB server A to another DB server B.
I have Schema ready with few datas in DB Server B but when I try to pull data from DB Server A to DB Server B,
I am getting following  error:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
> "Table 1".
>
> The conflict occurred in database"DB Server A", table "dbo.Parent Table",
> column 'xyz'.

The code which I used for this Operation:

```
INSERT INTO server1table
(X,Y,Z)
from server2.database.dbo.server2table
```

So what are the possible ways to do this operation taking care of key constraints?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

1. Copy data in the correct order. Find the parent child relationships and insert data to the parent tables first.
2. Drop or disable the constraints, insert the data, then recreate or re-enable the constraints.
3. Use a tool like Redgate SQL Data Compare, which will identify the heirachy and copy data in the correct order for you.

If you want to know more about how to find foreign key constraints there is a great post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/483193/4700939)